# Split text into 130 character long parts

Tags: php

I need to split an up to 2000 characters long text into 130 character long parts to store every single one into a database.

How to split the text into 130 character parts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [`chunk_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php) and [`wordwrap()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php). Combined with [`explode()`](http://php.net/explode) you could get an array of 130 character lines.

```
$chunks = explode('##', chunk_split($string, 130, '##'));
print_r($chunks);
```

**Note:** I've chosen `##` as a delimiter. This may need to be adjusted depending on your string.